# Adding ISNullOrEmpty

Tags: c#

I am currently running a statement that works totally fine, but now I need to amend it to say if reader[0] is null then only pull reader[1] but I can't get the syntax correct for updating that.  Can someone more experienced assist me?  Here is the code I am using:

```
List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
{
    tempList.Add(reader[0].ToString() + "_" + reader[1].ToString());
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
//if reader[0] is not null nor an empty string
if(reader[0] != null && reader[0].ToString() != "")
  tempList.Add(reader[0].ToString() + "_" + reader[1].ToString());
else
  tempList.Add(reader[1].ToString());
```